# Merging multiple IQueryable queries using Concat (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

Still not clear for me, I have two queries for example:

```
IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x => x.IsModerated == true);
IQueryable<Ad> list2 = db.Ads.Where(x => x.TypeId == 1);
IQueryable<Ad> list = list1.Concat(list2);

foreach(var item in list)
{
   ...
}
```

Is it going to be one database call or two?

Comment: Why not run profiler (or equivalent) and see.

Comment: In the constructor of the context, add `Database.Log = (s) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s)`, that will log to the output window of Visual Studio. You can then see how many requests are done with the generated SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It executes only once. this is an example of deferred execution and read this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/) for more details

```
IQueryable<Ad> list1 = db.Ads.Where(x => x.IsModerated == true); -- builds query 1, no db execution
IQueryable<Ad> list2 = db.Ads.Where(x => x.TypeId == 1); -- builds query 2, no db execution
IQueryable<Ad> list = list1.Concat(list2); -- -- builds combine query 'UNION ALL', no db execution

foreach(var item in list) -- query executes here
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: It can execute multiple queries, depending on what each query does. A single `IQueryable<T>` may even perform multiple queries

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I am curious to know the scenario for multiple executions. As per my understanding, `.Concat` will convert two queries into single `UNION ALL` query, so it will execute once.